# Creating a hierarchical multilevel donut chart with repeated categories within levels

Tags: python, r

I am trying to recreate this image with a new data set using either R or python.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmIOb.png)

The hierarchy is in this order Sequence Type -> O Antigen -> H Antigen. The issue I am running into is the repetition of groups within the nested rings (ie O25 repeated in ST131 and ST73, or H4 repeated in O25 and O117)

I have tried the webr::PieDonut however that is limited to 2 layers and wasn't correctly lining up the sections with the datatable used.

Datatable

```
   ï..Strain O.Type H.Type Sequence.Type Freq
1        #01    O45     H7         ST 95    1
2        #02    O45     H7         ST 95    1
3        #03     O1     H7         ST 95    1
4        #04     O6     H1         ST 73    1
5        #05    O25     H?        ST 131    1
6        #06     O2     H1         ST 73    1
7        #07    O25     H4        ST 131    1
8        #08     O6     H1         ST 73    1
9        #09    O25     H4        ST 131    1
10       #10    O86    H18         ST 38    1
11       #11    O75     H5        ST 550    1
12       #12     O1     H6        ST 648    1
13       #13     O?     H1         ST 73    1
14       #14    O25     H4        ST 131    1
15       #15     O2     H6        ST 141    1
16       #16    O25     H4        ST 131    1
17       #17    O86    H18         ST 38    1
18       #18     O6     H1         ST 73    1
19       #19     O1     H7         ST 95    1
20       #20    O25     H4        ST 131    1
21       #21    O25     H4        ST 131    1
22       #22    O75     H5        ST 404    1
23       #23     O6     H1          ST ?    1
24       #24     O1     H7         ST 59    1
25       #25    O45     H6        ST 405    1
26       #26     O?     H9        ST 410    1
27       #27     O8     H9        ST 410    1
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(webr)


PD = data %>% group_by(Sequence.Type, O.Type) %>% dplyr::summarise(n = sum(Freq))
print(PD)

PieDonut(PD, aes(O.Type, Sequence.Type, count=n), title = "Strain Collection - ST, O/H breakdown")
```

[PieDonut Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6bgT.png)

As you can see, the tibble used to generate the plot shows O2 belongs to ST141 and ST73 but the plot shows it as belonging with ST95

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   Sequence.Type [12]
   Sequence.Type O.Type     n
   <chr>         <chr>  <int>
 1 ST 131        O25        7
 2 ST 141        O2         1
 3 ST 38         O86        2
 4 ST 404        O75        1
 5 ST 405        O45        1
 6 ST 410        O8         1
 7 ST 410        O?         1
 8 ST 550        O75        1
 9 ST 59         O1         1
10 ST 648        O1         1
11 ST 73         O2         1
12 ST 73         O6         3
13 ST 73         O?         1
14 ST 95         O1         2
15 ST 95         O45        2
16 ST ?          O6         1
```

Any advice would be appreciated!